# Regular expression matching timezone label with offset

Tags: regex, timezone

I rarely use regular expression, now I want to use regular expression in validating a timezone entry. These entries are saved in DB and only the offset value is used.

Below are the valid entries:

```
Australian Central Time ( GMT+10:30 )
London - Greenwich Mean Time ( GMT+00:00 )
Beijing, Hong Kong (GMT+08:00)
Japan Standard Time (GMT+09:00)
Pacific Daylight Time (GMT-07:00 )
Pacific Standard Time (GMT-08:00)
Singapore Time( GMT+08:00)
Europe Time +1 (GMT+01:00)
```

What I want is to check that the entry format is something like:
`Any words and characters here like above( GMT+08:00)`. GMT, -/+, 2 digits hours, :, 2 digits minutes are fixed. `(` and `)` can have spaces.

Below are invalid entries:

```
Europe Time GMT+01:00
GMT+02:00
(GMT+01:30)
Hello
Philippines
Singapore Time (GMT + 08:00)
Singapore Time (GMT+8:0)
Singapore Time (UTC+08:00)
```

This is what I tried, but it is far from what I wanted:
`^[\w\s\+,-]+[\(\s]+[GMT]+[-\+]+[\d{2}]+[:]+[\d{2}]+[\)\s]+`

Thanks to @sleepwalk for his answer, I just tweak it a little to fit to my needs.

`.+\(\s*GMT+[+-]+\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*\)\s*`

Comment: You have put all parts of the pattern in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[...]` which matches 1 character out of the listed characters. This for example `[\d{2}]` matches a digit or chars `{` `}` `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
.*\(\s*GMT\s*[+-]?\s*\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*\)\s*
```

You can test your regexs here https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks! I just need to tweak it a little to fit to what I need :)